# abstracting away match in racket

Tags: racket

I have a couple of functions that matches for structs that look like such:

```
(define (get-bounding-y struct-lst)
    (flatten (for/list ([i struct-lst])
               (match i
                 [(line _ _ _ _ _ y1 _ y2)                 (list y1 y2)]
                 [(arc _ _ _ _ _ y radius _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _) (list (+ y radius) (- y radius))]
                 [(point _ _ _ _ _ y)                      (list y)]
                 [(path _ _ _ _ path-list)                 (get-bounding-y path-list)]))))
```

I would like to abstract this away so that a function of the structure

(matcher (struct-name1 return-value) (struct-name2 return-value) ...)

i.e. (matcher (line (+ 1 x1)) (arc radius) (point x) (path entities))
will return this:

```
(match a-struct
        [(struct* line  ([x1 x1]))              (+ 1 x1)]
        [(struct* arc   ([radius radius]))      radius]
        [(struct* point ([x x]))                x]
        [(struct* path  ([entities entities]))  entities])
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Should be easy with a macro, but your details seem to miss some stuff.

Comment: Hey, what details am i missing?

Comment: Given `(line x1)`, where is the usage of `x1`, or alternatively, what is the meaning of the 'binding' of `([x1 x1])`? Also, you would need to pass in `a-struct` somewhere to `matcher`.

Comment: Sorry, i've updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `match`. Custom patterns are defined with `define-match-expander`.

Let's say you have the struct

```
(struct line (x1 y1 x2 y2))
```

and you observe you are using the match pattern

```
(line _ y1 _ y2)
```

over and over. You prefer to write

```
(line* y1 y2)
```

Using `define-match-expander` you can turn `(line* y1 y2)` into `(line _ y1 _ y2)`.

Here is a complete example:

```
(define-match-expander line*
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_line* y1 y2)
       #'(line _ y1 _ y2)])))

(match (line 0 1 2 3)
  [(line* y1 y2) (list y1 y2)])
```

The output is:

```
'(1 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

This was what i wanted to do, but at the moment it's too specific:

1) it must always the 4 dot, line, arc, path syntax even if i only want to match 2 structs

2) the macro is defined in one file, and if i wanted to use functions defined in another file inside the syntax a, b, c, d,  it will give me an error "unbound identifier in module". What i want is a mixture of both the ability to integrate local functions and to pull out variables from the left side of the match but i haven't figured out how to do so yet.

```
(define-syntax match-struct
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ (dot a) (line b) (arc c) (path d))
       (with-syntax  ([tmp0 (syntax->datum #'a)]
                      [tmp1 (syntax->datum #'b)]
                      [tmp2 (syntax->datum #'c)])
       #'(lambda (a-struct)
           (match a-struct
             [(dot highlighted selected visible layer p)                                tmp0]
             [(line highlighted selected visible layer p1 p2)                           tmp1]
             [(arc highlighted selected visible layer center radius start end p1 p2 p3) tmp2]
             [(path highlighted selected visible layer entities)                        (d entities)])))])))
```